# How to add index to database with belongsTo association

Tags: cakephp

I'm looking for the best practice for adding an id to a database table. As an example I have a Member (model) that hasMany Recipe. The Recipe model states that it belongsTo Member:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Member' => array(
        'className' => 'Member',
        'foreignKey' => 'member_id',
    )
);
```

I hoped that this would be sufficient when saving new recipes to the database, but I see that cake cannot figure out the relationship on its own because I am getting an error ("General error: 1364 Field 'member_id' doesn't have a default value") when using add:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Recipe->create();
        if ($this->Recipe->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The recipe has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The recipe could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in this case I can easily get around the problem by adding

```
$this->request->data['Recipe']['member_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

but in general the ids that I will want to add will not be stored with the Auth data. So I would like to know how to access the id when saving something that belongsTo something else.

edit: I think my question was probably not worded well enough. I will restate what I'm looking for:

Say User hasMany A, which hasMany B, which hasMany C. C belongsTo B, A, and User (table for C contains user_id, a_id, and b_id). A user logs in, and picks a certain A, and then a certain B. The user now wants to add a new C. What is the best way to get all the id values for the new C entry? Do I just set a bunch of session variables? Should they all be passed in the URL? Is there some better way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide any information that you want to save in the database. This means you either use the Auth information like you already stated or you get the information via a form where you can select from all the members available.
Either way the information has to come from somewhere. It can not create itself out of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is selecting or picking A, B or C, them, somehow you can store their data and deal with them.

Usually, the common way is using forms. If you are using Javascript, you can set hidden inputs or if you are using AJAX, just using them inside it to call the final Cake functions.

You have to see how the user picks them, and then, store that ID in some variable to play with it. POST, GET, SESSIONS, COOKIES...